# need to optimise and test my code for custom application fee

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, stripe-payments, logic

I have worked on adding this functionality for Stripe fee and it seems to be working fine, however i need to be sure due to the criticality of the payments involved.

The goal here is to charge candidates for only processing months, which means only when they get a contribution for that month. For instance, if a candidate gets first contribution on 24th of nov 2023, that particular payment should be charged the extra fee.
However, the rest of the payments for that month should be normal. And again, the first payment coming after 24th of dec 2023, would be charged the extra fee.

contribution_form.rb

```
puts "starting else block  ----->>#{amount_cents}" 
        applicable_fee = candidate.determine_fee(amount_cents)
        Stripe::Charge.create({
          amount: amount_cents,
          currency: candidate.candidate_country[candidate.country.to_s.to_sym][:currency],
          source: stripe_token,
          application_fee_amount: applicable_fee,
        # application_fee_amount: ((amount_cents * ((candidate.merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25).to_i,
         statement_descriptor_suffix: "#{get_statement_descriptor.to_s.upcase}",
          on_behalf_of: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          transfer_data: {
            destination: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          },
        }, stripe_version: '2019-12-03',)
```

candidate.rb

```
  def determine_fee(amount_cents)
    amount = ((amount_cents * ((merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25).to_i
    return amount unless id ==  3954 
    if fee_paid_on["started_date"].nil? || (next_start_date(fee_paid_on["started_date"].to_datetime, true) <= Time.zone.now)
       amount = ((amount_cents * ((merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25 + 799).to_i
      fee_paid_details
    else 
      amount = ((amount_cents * ((merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25).to_i 
      fee_paid_details
    end
    amount
  end 
  
  def next_start_date(start_date, flag = false)
    puts "next start date ----->>#{start_date}"
    return start_date + 1.month if flag 
  
    t = Time.zone.now
    start_date.month != t.month ? Time.zone.parse("#{start_date.day}/#{t.month}/#{t.year}") : start_date + 1.month
  end  
  #only updating start date and setting it as per next month
  def  fee_paid_details 
    started_date =  fee_paid_on["started_date"]
    new_started_date = (next_start_date(started_date.to_datetime) < Time.zone.now ? started_date.to_datetime : next_start_date(started_date.to_datetime)) if started_date
    update_columns(
      fee_paid_on: {
        "started_date" => started_date.nil? ? Time.zone.now : new_started_date,
        "last_paid_on" => Time.zone.now 
      }
    )
  end
```

I need insight in 2 departments:

1. How do I thoroughly test this?
2. Can someone help me optimise my code

Answer (score 1):

In general, your implementation looks correct, though you'll likely need to do some more work if you accept multiple currencies as there is an exchange rate and conversion fees (Stripe charges an additional 2% for currency conversion). Assuming you don't need to worry about currency, and without knowing more about your integration, here are some considerations:

> How do I thoroughly test this?

The best way to test would be to compare the fees you calculated to the actual fees. You would check the `charge.application_fee_amount` against the fee on the [Balance Transaction](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-fee_details). You can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) the `charge.balance_transaction` object that Stripe returns after a Charge is created, by passing `expand` into the Charge creation parameters like below:

```
 Stripe::Charge.create({
          amount: amount_cents,
          currency: candidate.candidate_country[candidate.country.to_s.to_sym][:currency],
          source: stripe_token,
          application_fee_amount: applicable_fee,
        # application_fee_amount: ((amount_cents * ((candidate.merchant_rate.to_f * 100) + 2.9) / 100) + 25).to_i,
         statement_descriptor_suffix: "#{get_statement_descriptor.to_s.upcase}",
          on_behalf_of: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          transfer_data: {
            destination: candidate.stripe_gateway_id,
          },
          expand: ['balance_transaction'],
        }, 
          stripe_version: '2019-12-03',
        )
```

The above code will return the nested Balance Transaction object after Charge creation.

> Can someone help me optimise my code

It looks like you wrote out the calculations for `amount` three separate times, which doesn't adhere to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#:%7E:text=%22Don%27t%20repeat%20yourself%22,data%20normalization%20to%20avoid%20redundancy). Similarly you only need one line to return the `fee_paid_details` variable from the `determine_fee()` function, since it is being returned in both the `if` and `else` statements. One other thing I noticed is: you convert `started_date` from `string` to `datetime` a lot in your code. It would make more sense to keep it stored as a `datetime` variable and only convert it to a `string` once when you store it in your database.